# Glossaries and citation is not working in IEEEtran

Tags: bibliographies, glossaries, ieeetran

[image]I'm writing a paper and I faced this problem.
the below code produce the error in that attached photo [image]

the glossary contains only

```
\newglossaryentry{JMLD}{name=JMLD, description=joint maximum likelihood detection}
```

Section01 contains only

```
\cite{Diana2018} is \gls{JMLD}
```

bibliography.bib contains only

```
@INPROCEEDINGS{Diana2018, 
author={Dawoud, D. W. and F. Heliot and M. A. Imran and R. Tafazolli}, 
booktitle={IEEE Int. Conf. Commun., (ICC), Kansas City, MO}, 
title = {A novel orthogonal transmission scheme for visible light communication},
year={2018.}, 
month={May},}
```

but the code is not working, any idea what is the problem. Is it that I'm using a different folder for Section01, and what about the glossaries. Thanks in advance for your help

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\def\Conf{ICSPIS2021}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\input{glossary}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:SectionI}
\input{\Conf/Section01}

\printglossaries

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bstctlcite{BSTcontrol}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you checked that your MWE actually shows the problem? If I replace `\input{glossary}` by the single entry that you provide, `\input{\Conf/Section01}` by the line of text that you give, then `pdflatex` + `bibtex` + `makeglossaries` + 2*`pdflatex` does not give errors. The primary problem are the red lines at the top, which are cut off at the beginning, not the blue warnings. In the code that you included, I don't see anything that could produce such errors.

Comment: I updated the file, the warning it means that reference Diana2018 is not defined, while it is defined and it doesn't produce a bibliography

Comment: Remove the `\input` statement in your small example and replace it by the code from `Section01.tex` that you think is relevant. The red errors refer to line 30, but the main document doesn't have 30 lines, so the errors refer to a file that you do not show.

Comment: Regarding the reference: Did you run `bibtex` or `biber` to produce the `bbl` file?

Comment: I use my template for many years now, but this time I decided to do subfolders to organize my source files. It was working before fine

Comment: This is puzzling, but doesn't directly help to solve the problem. The screenshot from the error is still incomplete (in the error log, what came above the lines we see in your posting?), as the name of the file is missing to which the errors refer. It is definitely not the main file as there is no line 30 in it.

Comment: I created an entirely new file and I wrote the file line by line to make sure I'm not getting the error. But I still when I run the original file it is not working